# merge values (combine rows) certain rows based on time difference and certain other Ifs

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform some row operations based on timedelta and certain ifs on a dataframe.
Lets say I have a dataframe of the below nature:

```
    A   B  DateTime           Direction    Nom
a  6.5  1  2017-06-01 15:37     B          10  
b  6.8  0  
c  7    0  
f  6    1  16:21                S           6  
h  6.1  1  16:28                S           15  
i  6.2  0  
j
```

I would like to club the two rows f & h since they are
1. within 15 min time frame
2. Both have same direction (S)
3. The merged column should essentially have the sum of Nom(15+6) and the A value should be weighted average. Eg. (6*6 + 15*6.1 / 21) = 6.0714

Please note the row indexes are not serial - just in case..

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: I am trying to utilise the pd.timedelta('899s') to combine the two rows.
Lets say i create a new column which populates the delta between two rows.
However am not sure, how i can go back not just 1 row but sometimes 2. 3 or even 4rows if they are within 15 min and perform those arithmetic operations of summing, averaging ,etc

Comment: Hi @DYZ, Here is what am ending up doing.

Comment: @DYZ, Here is what am ending up doing:
1. Extract a df first which has all same Direction
2. Create new col for timedelta using to_timedelta feature
3. Create new col that will add the Nom based on timedelta criteria & one more IF condition that I have not specified in my question here
4. Create a new column for calculating the average A based on my timedelta, and the IF condition i just spoke in point 3 above.
5. Extract or merge these changed rows into my orig df
6. Work on merged/concatenated cols to ensure intergrity.
Please let me know if we can do this in some quick way :)